# A Confusing Limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, exponential-function

I am having trouble evaluating the limit of an infinite sum. The expression is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{n}{i}\right)$$

Now, for any fixed $n$, the terms in the tail of the sum goes to $\exp(0)=1$, so it clearly diverges. However, at the same time each term is going to $0$; If we actually "set" $n=\infty$, the sum is $0$. So, which one is the right approach? Is this limit actually defined?

Comment: Do you mean
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{n}{i}\right) $$
?

Comment: The limit of the sequence of series $$\begin{align}&1\\ &0+1\\ &0+0+1\\ &0+0+0+1\\&\quad\vdots\end{align}$$ is $1$, even though each term individually goes to $0$.

Comment: @Eff No I do not, although that is an interesting sum/limit too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the limit is not defined. For each $n\in\mathbb N$, the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac ni\right)$ diverges, since we don't have $\lim_{i\to\infty}\exp\left(-\frac ni\right)=0$. Therefore, it doesn't even make sense to study that limit.